# When is it a good idea to store passwords in clear text?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am working on an application that is targetted at non technical users. I expect a large number of support calls regarding lost passwords and inability to login.

I am using ASP.NET membership provider that provides 3 options for storing passwords - Clear text, Hashed, Encrypted.

Is it a good idea to store passwords in clear text given the nature of this application? Are there any legal issues involved in storing passwords in clear text?

Comment: **NEVER** Period.

Comment: haha, you probably get the idea it is a poor idea to store passwords in clear text. however, if you are expecting a large volume of lost passwords, you should implement an automated recovery system. said system autogenerates a random password, hashes to datastore, sends cleartext to client, and prompts for new password on login. just a suggestion :)

Comment: Just so you don't get the wrong idea from some of the answers, this is NOT a stupid question.  Until you've gone down this road, you just don't know.  :)

Comment: You could always enforce your passwords to be as complex as an MD5 hash, thus fooling any potential hacker

Comment: wow, tough crowd! Ok, I am not going to store the password as clear text. Since I do receive emails from big websites with clear text password, I assumed that there is some reason why they are doing this. Also, I wonder why ASP.NET membership API has this as an option if it's not a good idea.

Comment: No, I didn't think it was a stupid Q. If it was stupid, I'd assume MS would not have this option to begin with.

Comment: ASP.Net may offer it as an option for testing, prototyping or other uses that don't include real live users.

Comment: The minimum you can do is simply MD5 the passwords and use password resetting via an email

Comment: @unknown - None of those websites really care about user data or privacy and neither does Microsoft

Comment: Isn't the plain text for web.config stored passwords only?

Comment: @Chris it's possible to encrypt parts of the config files. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx and http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021506-1.aspx

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Never.

There is **never a good reason to store passwords in your database**, ever. Especially *not* in clear text. You should be storing the *hash* of the password **only**.

The *worst* thing you can do to a user is broadcast their "recovered" password across the Internet in a clear-text e-mail. It is *so easy* to simply store a one-way hash of the password which *cannot be recovered*.

For lost passwords, you simply *reset* their password and give them a temporary password which they have to change  when they log in. Safe and secure.

People often use the same passwords for multiple applications (especially non-technical users). So **your application will likely contain the passwords for people's bank accounts**, email, etc.

You have a *responsibility* to secure users' passwords, no matter how trivial your application is.

Comment: I agree with most of that, but there are applications like mint.com where their entire business model depends on storing your password in a recoverable format.  

But yeah, for this guy, he should be resetting passwords.

Comment: @brien, mint.com can store encrypted passwords in the DB, and recover/decrypt them when needed.

Comment: @notnoop - Yes, Mint's case is the same as anyone who has to secure sensitive data (bank records, private info, etc). That data just *happens* to be passwords. It's not *really* a password-management issue, per se.

Comment: +1 to that.  As for the "forgot password" dance, my technique is to generate a random temporary password (encrypted of course), store it separately from their normal password, and then email it to the user.  Then when the user logs in with that temporary password they're prompted to enter a new password.  This prevents the possibility of someone screwing with someone else's account, needlessly resetting their password.

Answer (score 21):

Here's a few reasons to use unencrypted passwords:

1. When you don’t respect your user’s privacy.
2. When you’re about to be fired from your current job and would like to leave a lasting impression.
3. When you would like your primary users to be Chinese hackers.

If you feel like any of those items match your business model, then go ahead and leave your passwords unencrypted.

Comment: ...but please tell me the name of your website/application *first*, just so's I can do business *with someone else*.

Answer (score 11):

No, never a good idea, no mather how silly your application is.

Answer (score 9):

When you want your site hacked and you have to *guarantee* that your user data is stolen or corrupted.

That's when you store passwords in clear text.

Comment: Maybe if he had a beef with his employer?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose there is one situation where storing passwords in clear-text is appropriate.

If you were writing an application to use as the "before" example in a demonstration on how to write secure code so that you could show how to implement password encryption/hashing techniques.

Comment: HAHAHA... or "programming malpractice 101"

Answer (score 2):

It is never a good idea to store password in database. Store a hash of password (possibly salted). In case of lost passwords, generate a new one and send it to their verified email address - make sure they change this autogenerated password on the next login.

Your target-audience may be non technical, but that won't be the case with their friends who are casual/professional pranksters. Non technical users must be treated with extra care because **they are more likely to keep same username/password combination** for your small application, the Google account and the online banking account (if the bank accepts that password). They will lose their data/mail accounts/money and you will lose trust and customers.

Here is a blog post on [storing passwords in databases](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000953.html) worth reading by [@codinghorror](http://twitter.com/codinghorror)

Answer (score 1):

Never. The "nature of the application" doesn't matter. You should ask yourself what you think the benefits of storing it in clear text are. Do you expect tech support to pick up the phone and tell them their password? Or email it to them when they forget it? Those are never good ideas.

There's an established design pattern for passwords:

1. Hash them
2. Provide the user with a Forgot Password link
3. User enters the email address associated with their account
4. Reset link or temp generated password is emailed to their address
5. They are immediately prompted to specify a new password upon visiting the link or using the temp password.

That's the general overview and it's the expected approach. Other variations exist, such as providing security questions.

Answer (score 1):

For any reliable information on legal reasons, consult a lawyer.  In the US, you should be able to get a referral from your local bar association.  I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.

That said, if you ever have a data breach you might be liable for anything that happens on your site, including the possibility of being responsible for anything financial or libellious.  If the user uses a password on multiple sites, you might possibly be liable for other activity on other sites.  In the US, you can get sued for pretty much anything, and it's not clear to me that you'd win such a suit.

So, the legal liabilities are potentially large.  Consult a lawyer before saving cleartext passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Security and Usability are at opposite ends of the same stick.  When you make you application easy to use, like giving the user their password back you make it insecure.  When you make your application ask 5 questions, a blood sample, and a password even Einstein would forget, you have usability problems.

Comment: Not in this case. The easiest way to provide login recovery is to e-mail the user a one-time link to a "choose a new password" form. This is actually *easier* to use than either a password reminder or (certainly) a new randomly generated password.

Comment: That method tends to be towards the middle of usability and security.  Bank legislation requires banks use 2 forms of security in their applications, which is one reason they use the security questions so much.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea if you have usability in mind and less effort from an user perspective.

However, you have to understand that, as a developer, you need to guarantee your users safety online. What the user wants is not always the best for them.

People use the same password in a lot of accounts. If your db is compromised in some way, you're giving away passwords that can be being used in bank accounts for example.

If you think that resetting password it not for non-techie people, at least create a form to change the password like Gmail does.

I don't know in US, but at least in my country, if a compromised system stored my passwords in it, I would try to sue them, because **we have** ways to prevent storing clear text passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You should only store passwords in clear text when you want it to be really easy for anyone to obtain them. For your usecase I would suggest an option where the user enters their e-mailadress and gets an e-mail containing a link with which they can log in. When logged in they should have the option to change password if they want to, but if most users aren't frequent visitors, they might not even want to change their password as they'll forget it before next visit.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously I do not think it is a good idea ever ...